# How to calculate quantization error from 16bit to 8bit?

Tags: c++, c, math

Does anyone know how to calculate the error of quantizing from 16bit to 8bit?

I have looked at the Wikipedia article about [Quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)), but it doesn't explain this.

Can anyone explain how it is done?

Lots of love,
Louise

Update: My function looks like this.

```
unsigned char quantize(double d, double max) {
  return (unsigned char)((d / max) * 255.0);
}
```

Comment: I think your function is close. It can use some error checking - e.g max better not be zero, both values probably should be positive. I would suggest unit-testing it to be 100% sure. When do you expect the output to be zero? When 255?

Comment: It looks like max is intended to be the maximum value of the sample 'd'. The code doesn't enforce it, though - d can take very small negative values or very large positive values, resulting in output that isn't in the range 0-255 (which appears to be the intent.) Also, what's the output data supposed to be? Unsigned audio samples centered around 128?  Any negative values will result in the return range being [-255, 255], which probably isn't what you intend.

Comment: By the way, from reading other questions you posted I get the impression that your 16 bit sample values aren't 16 bit sample values at all. If you start out with 16 bit PCM samples and run an FFT on them (which I wouldn't do without normalizing the samples first) you end up with FFT coefficients, which aren't 16 bit sample values. They're something else. Maybe you should just describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ori: I use a library to do all the FFT and normalization work for me. What I have made is a program that transforms 16bit audio into 8bit spectrograms. So I just wanted to know how big an error this is made when going from 16bit to 8bit.

Comment: In that case, the only meaningful error is when going from the 8 bit spectrogram back to 16 bit audio. The way I'll do that is to dequantize the 8 bit spectrogram, run it through an inverse Fourier transform and subtract that from the original samples, giving you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there in the Wikipedia article, expressed as signal to noise ratio.  But I guess the real question is, in what units do you want the result?  As a signal to noise power ratio, it's 20 log(2^8) = 55 dB

You probably need to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel

Comment: So I guess it is the SQNR values I have to calculate and subtract?
SQNR_16 - SQNR_8 = 20*log_10(2^16) - 20*log_10(2^8) = 48.165 dB Or should it be SQNR = 20*log10(2^(16-8)) = 55dB, if I want to know the error going from 16bit to 8bit?

Comment: The latter, 55 dB going from 16 bit to 8 bit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to convert both the 16-bit value and the 8-bit value to their respective analog values that they represent and then take the difference between those. To stick with the wikipedia entries, here is [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_error) that talks about it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the error is the difference between the reconstituted quantized signal and the original signal.

Say your original series is Xi, and you quantize by doing an integer division by q - you get a series of integer values int(Xi/q). Your error term is e = Xi - q*int(Xi/q).

For example: a sample value of 60000 divided by 256 gives 234. 234*256 = 59904 after dequantization. The quantization error is 60000-59904=96.

Comment: That might come in handy. Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting that if you treat last 8 bits as signed char, it gives you correct quantization error.

```
char absolute_quatization_error(short measurement) //lets consider that short is 16bits
{
   return (measurement & 0xFF);
}
```

Ok upper function is tricky you should use something like.

```
short absolute_quatization_error(short measurement) //lets consider that short is 16bits
{
    short r;
    r=measurement & 0xFF;
    if (r>0x7F)
        return (0xFF-r);
    else
        return r;
}
```

If you need relative error you should use.

```
float relative_quatization_error(short measurement)
{
     return 1.0*absolute_quatization_error(measurement)/((float)measurement); //i did not check if this correctly converts to float.
}
```